# What does て form + すらいた mean?

Tags: grammar

> ただの荷物持ち、と話していたリリの言葉が蘇る。本当にそうなのかと、前まで**憧れてすらいた**冒険者像へ失望に近い感情を抱いてしまう。

I'm not sure how to interpret this part of the sentence. What does the すらいた do?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have time to answer this in depth, but it's 憧れて＋すら＋いた, and する is like a more formal も.

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/120264/meaning/m0u/　「すら」って、「さえ」に似てると思う・・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すら means "even".

憧れていた --> adored, yearned to be one
憧れてすらいた --> even adored, even yearned to be one (≒憧れてさえいた)